# How can I transport a Git repo from one PC to another when the files are (probably) current?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-pull, git-extensions, git-fetch

I have a project on `PC1` that I have been using `GitExtensions` and `BitBucket` to manage.  Because of pre-git activity, the folder is pretty much replicated on another (remote) machine `PC2`, but there is no `git` repo there, and I want to export the existing `git` repo so that I get `PC2` up-to-date with commits and other activity that are on `PC1` and on `BitBucket`.

I want to do it as a `fetch` then `merge` operation, partly because I'm not totally sure the two PC's are aligned, and I want to see whats going on.

I tried to do it with a `GitExtensions` `pull` but after fetching when I tried a `merge` it was obviously going to complain that every existing file would be overwritten.  Similarly if I try a `commit`, it decides it is going to update every file in the repo.

I'm just curious as to what the accepted "`git`" way of accomplishing this - how I can set `PC2` up so that there isn't an initial mass overwriting of every source file?

Would transferring the entire `.git\` folder tree from `PC1` to `PC2` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, transferring the `.git` directory is actually somewhat reasonable.  Once you copy the `.git` directory from PC1 to PC2, you can run `git status` or `git diff` on PC2 to see what is different on PC2.

Comment: OK, I tried copying the repo.  `git status` and `git diff` still show every file as different, but I suspect this is now a line ending issue.  Just have to find that option....

Comment: A couple ways to do that: you can change how Git sees the files with a .gitattributes file, or you can convert the files with unix2dos or dos2unix.

Comment: I have spent the best part of an hour reading all the S/O posts on `autocrlf` and I am still none the wiser!  I don't think there is a `git` topic that exposes such a wide range of opinions.  I'm leaning towards a global `core.autocrlf=true` and `safecrlf=????`.  My situation is all PCs are Windows, I prefer all source files to have CRLFs in them on disk (and don't care how they are in the repo).  What are your suggestions for these config options?

Comment: If you want CRLF everywhere, then you can leave `core.autocrlf = false` and that will mean that the CRLF will be stored in the repo, and should give you the most predictable behavior.

Comment: OK, is there then a danger that lone `LF`'s in binary files will be folded to `CRLF`'s ?  I want the "leave everything as it is" option.

Comment: That's exactly why `core.autocrlf = false` is the safe, predictable option.  You make CRLFs in your text editor, and Git will just keep everything exactly as it is in the repo.

Comment: Note that `git diff` has the `--ignore-space-at-eol`, `--ignore-all-space`, `--ignore-space-change`, etc. options.